# How to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true in a Spring boot 2.1.0 starter configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I maintain a spring-boot-starter that customizes the error attributes returned when, for instance, an unknown endpoint is called.
This is done by overriding the `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes` bean.

Everything worked fine with 2.0.6, but [2.1.0 disables bean overriding by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes), making the starter now fail with the following message.

> Invalid bean definition with name 'errorAttributes' defined in class
> path resource
> [com/mycompany/springboot/starter/config/ErrorsConfig.class]: Cannot
> register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
> abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=com.mycompany.springboot.starter.config.ErrorsConfig;
> factoryMethodName=errorAttributes; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
> [com/mycompany/springboot/starter/config/ErrorsConfig.class]] for bean
> 'errorAttributes': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
> abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
> factoryMethodName=errorAttributes; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]
> bound

As explained in the documentation setting the `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` property to true fixes the problem.
My question is how to do that **in the starter** (I do not want the users of my starter to have to change their application.properties file, for something that is specific to my starter)?

I tried to a `@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mycompany/starter/application.properties")` annotation to my `@Configuration` with that property defined in that file, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing? Is there any way to allow my configuration to override that bean?

Here is the (simplified) source code of the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mycompany/starter/application.properties")
public class ErrorsConfig {
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Bean
    public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
        return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(WebRequest request, boolean includeStackTrace) {
                Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace);
                // CustomeError is a (simplified) bean of the error attributes we should return.
                CustomError err = new CustomError("myErrorCode", (String) errorAttributes.get("error"));
                return OBJECT_MAPPER.convertValue(err, Map.class);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and my resource file `com/mycompany/starter/application.properties` contains

> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Spring Boot's `ErrorAttributes` bean is defined by `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration`. It is annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` so it will back off if an `ErrorAttributes` bean has already been defined. As the bean defined by your `ErrorsConfig` class is attempting to override Boot's `ErrorAttributes` bean rather than causing it to back off, your `ErrorsConfig` class must be getting processed after Boot's `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` class. This means that you have an ordering problem in your starter.

The order in which auto-configuration classes are processed can be controlled using `@AutoConfigureBefore` and `@AutoConfigureAfter`. Assuming that `ErrorsConfig` is itself an auto-configuration class registered in `spring.factories`, you can fix your problem by annotating it with `@AutoConfigureBefore(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)`. With this change in place `ErrorsConfig` will define its `ErrorAttributes` bean before `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` attempts to do so which will cause the auto-configuration of Boot's `ErrorsAttribute` bean to back off.

Comment: Andy: What if ErrorsConfig is not auto-configuration? Is there a similar mechanism or do I have to use unique name or exclude the ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration?

Comment: Normal configuration should run before any auto-configuration. If you're not writing your own auto-configuration you should not have the problem addressed here.

Comment: I've created a small sample that shows the behaviour with spring-batch: https://github.com/JorgenRingen/spring-boot-spring-batch-bean-overriding
I'm adding @EnableBatchProcessing and configuring my own JobLauncher bean with the same name as the spring-batch autoconfiguration uses and get 
error-message telling that a bean with that name already exists on classpath (let me know if I should raise an issue on github)

Comment: @jorgen.ringen That problem really isn't related to this question and answer. Batch expects the `JobLauncher` to be provided via a `BatchConfigurer` bean rather than being directly configured as a bean.

Answer (score 15):

Easier solution would be to add this property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in the `application.properties`.

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception#4-beans-coming-from-3rd-party-libraries)

Comment: A starter shouldn’t have an `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue. But the problem in my case is that, I was using @Entity annotaion in my model class. I was using mongodb for the backend so entity was from Jpa and hence resulted in this issue. Once I removed that it started working